# TeamCity: Artifacts getting truncated

Tags: tcp, teamcity

We have a build chain, where a dependency builds it's project on a build agent(Windows) and uploads the artifacts to the TeamCity server.

Afterwards, a dependent collects those build artifacts, so it downloads those build artifacts from the TC server to the build agent(Mac OS). But one or few artifacts are getting truncated, that is, their size is not the same as original. They are smaller.

What measures can we take to check why is this taking place? How can the cause be determined? It is a large company so I am not sure how TC server is hosted, but I think it is on a Kubernetes server.

Comment: what if download artifact directly from tc-server using browser? is it truncated?

Comment: @daggett When I downloaded manually, the file size was correct!